# The order of the normalizer of a $p$-subgroup of $S_{p}$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory, p-groups

I found it In Exercise in abstract algebra by Dummit and Foote.

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-group of $S_p$.

What is the order of $N_{S_p}(P)$?

Comment: What is the meaning of `????`?

Comment: I used to use many ????? for emphasis.

Comment: FYI, be aware that this only makes you look childish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\;n_p\;$ denotes the number of Syloy $\;p\,-$ subgroups, then we know that

$$n_p=[S_p:N_G(P)]=\frac{p!}{|N_G(P)|}$$

and we know that $\;n_p=(p-2)!\;$